# MS Word Bullets in styles disappearing in O365/2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, bullets

Similar to this old thread [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/disappearingglitching-bullets/6efead0b-b55a-4461-b405-e74f64d001ae?page=3), but new problem the last 6 months or so.

Background: Everyone on the team uses Word 2016 (full local application) as part of our Enterprise O365 setup. Everyone is on Win10. We work on documents stored on SharePoint Online, and collaborate daily across hundreds of files. We use a custom set of tools (theme, color, style sheet) that have not had a problem for the last two years we've used them.

For the last few months or so, multiple users (including myself) have experienced "disappearing bullets". The margin indentation is there, but no bullet. You can fix it (temporarily) by modifying the style to re-select the font color - which is sometimes on none and sometimes still correct custom color or automatic) and they appear again. Sometimes not. Sometimes they show until you print, and then they disappear when you go back to the document.

I have found nothing consistent in all my troubleshooting. I've tried rebuilding & redeploying the style sheet - no joy yet.

- I haven't been able to pin it on a particular Windows/office update.
- I thought it might be tied to Acrobat Pro but it doesn't seem to be related to print drivers.
- It isn't only documents saved on SharePoint.
- Sometimes the bullets appear properly in the body of the document but don't appear in the Quick Styles menu properly.

I'm at a complete loss and open to any suggestions for solving or further troubleshooting.

Comment: Ideas: corruption in `Normal.dotm`; bad add-on.

Comment: @harrymc - would the corrupt normal.dotm affect a dozen+ people?

Comment: If it's shared. That's why I also asked about an add-on.

Comment: Ah- no, not shared. We just have each person put the theme/style/color xml files on their own machine. I wonder if somehow one person's was corrupted and it blew up everyone else's with all the shared files and copy/pasting that goes around.

Comment: You could compare the files from a bad and good computers, then  from two bad computers, to locate by common bad files that are different from the good one.